# How to load the file from the inputstream?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.groovy");
```

I need to pass this resource to the method called `parse` which takes `File` as param, so doing so fails:

```
new GroovyShell().parse(new FileInputStream(in));
```

How I can convert `FileInputStream` to `File` in java?

Comment: Which api are you using? Are you sure the parse method does not have overloaded params for (Reader, filename) or (Reader)?

Comment: `GroovyShell` look at here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html

Comment: So you do have it: new BufferedReader(new FileReader("//path//to//test.groovy"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use: [GroovyShell#parse(Reader)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html#parse(java.io.Reader)) method:

```
Script result = new GroovyShell().parse(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Comment: its giving me null pointer exception. How should i make sure that `test.groovy` is in classpath?

Comment: Which line is giving NPE? See updated answer. Is your `InputStream` valid?

Comment: I can see only `test.class` is in my classpath, not the `test.groovy` file. Hence I'm getting NPE. Any idea, why does `test.groovy` is not in class path?

Comment: That depends how you load the classes. In which folder you keep groovy file? Just to test try providing full path to groovy file for creating `InputStream` object.

Comment: Are you getting file not found error now or some other parse error?

Comment: Nope I'm still getting the NPE.

Comment: Which line gives you NPE with full path of groovy file?

Comment: The `InputStream` itself null, even if I give the full path

Comment: Difficult to guess from here as I created a sample groovy script and loaded/parsed it without any error.

Comment: Are you creating the input stream like InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fullpath); ?

Comment: I followed examples given her: http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2009/11/groovy-goodness-running-groovy-scripts.html

Comment: [Also this official doc has many examples](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy)

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
try {
    URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.groovy");
    File file = new File(url.toURI());
    new Shell().parse(file);
} catch(...){...}
```

if you know exact path to "test.groovy", do this:

```
new Shell().parse(new File("path/to/test.groovy"));
```

Comment: `url` is being null :(

Comment: are u sure "test.groovy" does exist in classpath?

Comment: Its there in the `${BASE_DIR}/test.groovy`

Comment: easily do this : `new Shell().parse(new File("${BASE_DIR}/test.groovy"));`